# Java project using read file, write file and arrays

Tags: java, arrays, file

i have an assignment that im having alot of trouble with and really need some help, iv got so far but am now stuck and have been stuck for several days. Here is the brief.

Students taking the first year of a degree in Irrational Studies take two modules: IR101 and IR102. The rules of assessment stipulate the following:
Students must pass both modules in order to proceed to Stage 2.
The pass mark for a module is 40.
Students who do not pass both modules will be deemed to have failed.
Students who fail only one of the two modules will be allowed a resit attempt.
Students who fail both modules will be required to repeat the year.
Students who pass both modules will be awarded a class based on their aggregate mark using the following scale:
70 – 100    1st
60 – 69.9   2.1
50 – 59.9   2.2
40 – 49.9   3rd
The aggregate mark is the mean of the two module marks
A list of students taking Irrational Studies is contained in the following file. Each line of the file contains a student id number (an integer) followed by the student’s name (a string).

IRstudent.txt includes:
 25987 Alan
 25954 Betty
 25654 Chris
 25622 David
 25321 Elsie
 25220 Fiona
 25212 Greg
 25218 Helen
 25147 Ian
 25196 Jim

The marks obtained by the students are contained in the following two files. Each line contains the student’s id number followed by the mark they obtained (a double). (Note that the students do not appear in the same order in the three files.)

IR101.txt includes:
25220 68.3
25212 70.5
25218 62.1
25147 38.3
25196 52.0
25987 35.6
25954 70.2
25654 58.6
25622 65.0
25321 51.5

IR102.txt includes:
25987 20.7
25954 63.4
25218 53.4
25147 47.5
25196 49.8
25654 35.1
25622 57.8
25321 45.6
25220 75.6
25212 72.5

Your task is to write a program that reads in the information from the three files and outputs a list of transcripts, ordered in descending order of aggregate mark, to a file in the current directory called “RankedList.txt”.
A transcript comprises three lines:
Line 1: Student id followed by student name
Line 2: Both module marks followed by the aggregate mark
    Marks should show one digit after the decimal point.
Line 3: The class and the outcome.
The class should be Fail, 3rd, 2.1, 2.2, or 1st.
The outcome should be Repeat Year, Resit a specified exam or Proceed to Stage 2.
In the transcript list, each transcript should be separated by a row of “-“. The following is an example extract from such a list:

37695    Aristotle
IR101    52.0    IR102   49.8    Aggregate   50.9
Class:   2.2     Outcome: Proceed to Stage 2

37622    Socrates
IR101    38.3    IR102   47.5    Aggregate   42.9
Class:   Fail    Outcome: Resit IR101

You may assume that the input file contains no errors.

Now iv got as far as opening the files and reading them but am stuck from there on. Here is my code so far.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Task2 {

public Scanner input;
int reg;
double ir101,ir102l;
double aggregate;
String student_name;
ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();

public void openIRstud()throws Exception{
    JFileChooser IRstudchooser = new JFileChooser();
    if(IRstudchooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        java.io.File inFile = IRstudchooser.getSelectedFile();
        input = new Scanner(inFile);
        System.out.println("IRstudents file read successfully.");
    }
}
public void openIR101()throws Exception{
    JFileChooser IR101chooser = new JFileChooser();
    if(IR101chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        java.io.File inFile = IR101chooser.getSelectedFile();
        input = new Scanner(inFile);
        System.out.println("IR101 file read successfully.");
    }
}
public void openIR102()throws Exception{
    JFileChooser IR102chooser = new JFileChooser();
    if(IR102chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        java.io.File inFile1 = IR102chooser.getSelectedFile();
        input = new Scanner(inFile1);
        System.out.println("IR102 file read successfully.");
    }
}
public void readIRstud (){
    while(input.hasNext()){
        String irstudid = input.next();
        String irname = input.next();
        System.out.printf(" %s %s\n", irstudid, irname);
    }
    System.out.println("Complete.");
}
public void readIR101 (){
    while(input.hasNext()){
        String ir101studid = input.next();
        String ir101mark = input.next();
        System.out.printf(" %s %s\n", ir101studid, ir101mark);
    }
    System.out.println("Complete.");
}
public void readIR102 (){
    while(input.hasNext()){
        String ir102studid = input.next();
        String ir102mark = input.next();
        System.out.printf(" %s %s\n", ir102studid, ir102mark);
    }
    System.out.println("Complete.");
}
public void Student(){
    while (input.hasNext()) {
        String line = input.nextLine();
        Student e = new Student();
        e.reg = Integer.parseInt(line.split(" ")[0]);
        e.ir101 = Double.parseDouble(line.split(" ")[1]);
        students.add(e);
    }
}
}
```

And here is my main (So far this only tests that the files are read, and that it stores in an array which im not even sure if that works) P.S this is a separate class.

```
import java.io.IOException;


public class Task2test {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
    Task2 r = new Task2();

    System.out.println("***** Marks Processing *****");
    System.out.println("Please select a file for IRstudents:");
    r.openIRstud();
    System.out.println("Now reading file IRstudents.");
    r.readIRstud();
    r.Student();

    System.out.println("Please select a file for IR101:");
    r.openIR101();
    System.out.println("Now reading IR101.");
    r.readIR101();
    r.Student();

    System.out.println("Please select a file for IR102:");
    r.openIR102();
    System.out.println("Now reading IR102.");
    r.readIR102();

}
}
```

Any help in accomplishing this will be much appreciated, im near ready to pull my hair out! thank you!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what it is you're asking, though.  I can see that you're stuck; that's why you're asking the question.  But what specifically is the trouble you're having?

Comment: Just knowing what to do after the point im at, im not sure what to do with the array ect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must first distinguish between tasks.

1 - Define the classes that you will need to your project.

2 - Define their functions.

3 - Read IRstudent.txt file and create a list of studests.

4 - Read IR101.txt file and associate the marks with the students.

5 - Read IR102.txt file and associate the marks with the students.

6 - Generate the agregate mark and the outcame class for the students.

7 - Order by agregate mark the students.

8 - Create a new file RankedList.txt to store the result.

9 - Write the students information to this file.

So lets go step by step.

**1 - Define the classes that you will need to your project.**

Class Student.

- idStudent
- name
- markIR101
- markIR102
- agregateMark

Class RankedList

- List
- classs
- outcome

**2 - Define their functions.**

Class Student

- List getStudentList(java.io.File irStudentsFile);
- void setIR101Mark(java.io.File ir101File, List sudents);
- void setIR102Mark(java.io.File ir102File, List sudents);

Class RankedList

- List students;
- addStudent(Student student);
- orderByAgregateMark();
- writeToFile();

** STEPS 3, 4, 5, 6 **

Here is a sample of code to solve your problem, but I did only until the step 6, and now I believe that you have condition to finish the project.

```
   import java.io.File;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.math.BigDecimal;
   import java.math.BigInteger;
   import java.util.LinkedList;
   import java.util.List;
   import java.util.StringTokenizer;
   import java.util.function.Consumer;
   import java.util.logging.Level;
   import java.util.logging.Logger;
   import java.util.stream.Stream;

   public class Student {

private int idStudent;
private String name;
private BigDecimal ir101Mark;
private BigDecimal ir102Mark;
private BigDecimal agregateMark;

public int getIdStudent() {
    return idStudent;
}

public void setIdStudent(int idStudent) {
    this.idStudent = idStudent;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public BigDecimal getIr101Mark() {
    return ir101Mark;
}

public void setIr101Mark(BigDecimal ir101Mark) {
    this.ir101Mark = ir101Mark;
}

public BigDecimal getIr102Mark() {
    return ir102Mark;
}

public void setIr102Mark(BigDecimal ir102Mark) {
    this.ir102Mark = ir102Mark;
}

public BigDecimal getAgregateMark() {
    return agregateMark;
}

public void setAgregateMark(BigDecimal agregateMark) {
    this.agregateMark = agregateMark;
}

public static List<Student> getStudentList(java.io.File irStudentsFile){

    List<Student> students = new LinkedList<>();
    Stream<String> lines;
    try {
        lines = java.nio.file.Files.lines(irStudentsFile.toPath());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        return null;
    }

    lines.forEach((Consumer<? super String>) line -> 
        {
            Student student = new Student();
            StringTokenizer sToken = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");
            student.setIdStudent(Integer.valueOf(sToken.nextToken()));
            student.setName(sToken.nextToken());

            students.add(student);
        } 

    );

    return students;
}

public static void setIR101Mark(java.io.File ir101File, List<Student> students){
    Stream<String> lines;
    try {
        lines = java.nio.file.Files.lines(ir101File.toPath());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        return;
    }

    lines.forEach((Consumer<? super String>) new Consumer<String>() {

        @Override
        public void accept(String line) {
            Student student = null;
            StringTokenizer sToken = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");
            int idStudent = Integer.valueOf(sToken.nextToken());

            for (Student student1 : students) {
                if (student1.getIdStudent() == idStudent) {
                    student = student1;
                }
            }

            if (student == null) {
                return;
            }

            student.setIr101Mark(BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.valueOf(sToken.nextToken())));
        }
    }
    );
}

public static void setIR102Mark(java.io.File ir102File, List<Student> students){
    Stream<String> lines;
    try {
        lines = java.nio.file.Files.lines(ir102File.toPath());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        return;
    }

    lines.forEach((Consumer<? super String>) new Consumer<String>() {

        @Override
        public void accept(String line) {
            Student student = null;
            StringTokenizer sToken = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");
            int idStudent = Integer.valueOf(sToken.nextToken());

            for (Student student1 : students) {
                if (student1.getIdStudent() == idStudent) {
                    student = student1;
                }
            }

            if (student == null) {
                return;
            }

            student.setIr102Mark(BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.valueOf(sToken.nextToken())));
        }
    }
    );
}

public static void agregateMark(List<Student> students){
    students.forEach(student ->{
        BigDecimal agregate = 
                student.getIr101Mark()
                .add(student.getIr102Mark())
                .divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.valueOf(2)));

        student.setAgregateMark(agregate);
    });
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    File irStudentFile = new File("D:\\IRstudent.txt");
    File ir101File = new File("D:\\IR101.txt");
    File ir102File = new File("D:\\IR102.txt");
    List<Student> students = Student.getStudentList(irStudentFile);
    Student.setIR101Mark(ir101File, students);
    Student.setIR102Mark(ir102File, students);
    Student.agregateMark(students);



    System.out.println("*** List of students ***");
    students.forEach(student -> {
        System.out.println("id: " + student.getIdStudent());
        System.out.println("Name: " + student.getName());
        System.out.println("IR 101 Mark: " + student.getIr101Mark());
        System.out.println("IR 102 Mark: " + student.getIr102Mark());
        System.out.println("Agregate Mark: " + student.getAgregateMark());
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------");
    });
}
```

}